# What is the most efficient way to reshape a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Given the following dataframe:

```
Number    Color1    Color2
 1         Red      Yellow
 2         Green    Blue
```

How can I reshape this dataframe around the "Number" column?

Expected output

```
Number    Color
  1        Red
  1        Yellow
  2        Green
  2        Blue
```

Note: The column names may not always be similar (Color1 and Color2 could be anything and aren't related)

Comment: `df.set_index('Number').stack().reset_index(drop=True, level=1)`

Comment: df.melt('Number')

Answer (score 0):

For that you can use the stack method from pandas. Here's a link to the pandas doc, and for its inverse, unstack
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html#pandas.DataFrame.stack
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html

Answer (score 0):

`df.set_index('Number').stack().reset_index(drop=True, level=1)`?

Comment: Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation.  Code only answers are not considered "good" answers.  From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review).